# bad performence mdb Duplicate messages receiving from jms provider

Tags: java, weblogic, spring-batch, spring-jms

We are using `defaultmessagelistenercontainer` with weblogic jms provider with 25 consumers and 100 tasks. We are using transacted session. We have getting duplicate messages most of the time.  May I know why?

Below  is the spring configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="MyListner"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="localQueueConnectionFactory" />
        <beans:property name="destination" ref="MyLocalQueue" />
        <beans:property name="messageListener" ref="MyLocalMessageListener" />
        <!-- <beans:property name="acknowledge" value="transacted" /> -->
        <beans:property name="concurrentConsumers" value="25" />
        <beans:property name="maxMessagesPerTask" value="100" />
        <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsLocalTransactionManager" />
        <beans:property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: You should either set the `sessionTransacted`to `true` or set a `transactionManager` but not both. Just remove the transactionManager please. For the duplication, what makes you think you receive a duplicate message? Does the queue itself contains duplicates maybe?

Comment: thank you for your reply. can you explain more about duplication.

Comment: their is no chance for queue containing duplicates because we only posting messages by fetching from db. when we have observed same message is processing 2 times.

Comment: I don't have enough details to help you. If you can share a project that reproduces the problem, we can certainly have a look to it.